# Javascript problem

Tags: javascript, scope

I'll admit I was not thinking straight when I wrote this...

Memory Test

#### The numbers are...

```
        </div>
        <div id="email">
            <input id="a"></input>
            <input id="b"></input>
            <input id="c"></input>
            <input id="d"></input>
            <input id="e"></input>
            <input id="f"></input>
            <input id="g"></input>
            <input id="h"></input>
            <input id="i"></input>
        </div>
        <script>
        function timeMsg()
        {
        var t=setTimeout("alertMsg()",500);
        }
        function alertMsg()
        {
            document.getElementById('remember').innerHTML = ('<h3>Times up partner, what were they?</h3></br><input name="one" id="one" type="text"></input></br><input id="answer" type="button" value="Next" onClick="changeSet()"/>');
            document.getElementById('number').value = 'no cheating...';
            }

        function changeSet() {
            var s=setTimeout("alertYea()",500);
            var a=document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = (document.getElementById("one").value);
            document.getElementById('remember').innerHTML = ('<p id="bumper">2</p>');
            document.getElementById('number').value = '9264';
        }
        function alertYea() {
            document.getElementById('remember').innerHTML = ('<h3>Times up partner, what were they?</h3></br><input name="two" id="two" type="text"></input></br><input id="answer" type="button" value="Next" onClick="changeSet2()"/>');
            document.getElementById('number').value = 'no cheating...';

            }

        function changeSet2() {
            var a=setTimeout("alertYea2()",500);
            var b=document.getElementById('b').innerHTML = (document.getElementById("two").value);
            document.getElementById('remember').innerHTML = ('<p id="bumper">3</p>');
            document.getElementById('number').value = '38671';
        }

        function alertYea2() {
            document.getElementById('remember').innerHTML = ('<h3>Times up partner, what were they?</h3></br><input name="three" id="three" type="text"></input></br><input id="answer" type="button" value="Next" onClick="changeSet3()"/>');
            document.getElementById('number').value = 'no cheating...';

            }

        function changeSet3() {
            var a=setTimeout("alertYea3()",500);
            var c=document.getElementById('c').innerHTML = (document.getElementById("three").value);
            document.getElementById('remember').innerHTML = ('<p id="bumper">4</p>');
            document.getElementById('number').value = '938263';
        }

        function alertYea3() {
            document.getElementById('remember').innerHTML = ('<h3>Times up partner, what were they?</h3></br><input name="four" id="four" type="text"></input></br><input id="answer" type="button" value="Next" onClick="changeSet4()"/>');
            document.getElementById('number').value = 'no cheating...';

            }

        function changeSet4() {
            var a=setTimeout("alertYea4()",500);
            var d=document.getElementById('d').innerHTML = (document.getElementById("four").value);
            document.getElementById('remember').innerHTML = ('<p id="bumper">5</p>');
            document.getElementById('number').value = '8351032';
        }

        function alertYea4() {
            document.getElementById('remember').innerHTML = ('<h3>Times up partner, what were they?</h3></br><input name="five" id="five" type="text"></input></br><input id="answer" type="button" value="Next" onClick="changeSet5()"/>');
            document.getElementById('number').value = 'no cheating...';

            }

        function changeSet5() {
            var a=setTimeout("alertYea5()",500);
            var e=document.getElementById('e').innerHTML = (document.getElementById("five").value);
            document.getElementById('remember').innerHTML = ('<p id="bumper">6</p>');
            document.getElementById('number').value = '02619815';
        }

        function alertYea5() {
            document.getElementById('remember').innerHTML = ('<h3>Times up partner, what were they?</h3></br><input name="six" id="six" type="text"></input></br><input id="answer" type="button" value="Next" onClick="changeSet6()"/>');
            document.getElementById('number').value = 'no cheating...';

            }

        function changeSet6() {
            var a=setTimeout("alertYea6()",500);
            var f=document.getElementById('f').innerHTML = (document.getElementById("six").value);
            document.getElementById('remember').innerHTML = ('<p id="bumper">7</p>');
            document.getElementById('number').value = '274619523';
        }

        function alertYea6() {
            document.getElementById('remember').innerHTML = ('<h3>Times up partner, what were they?</h3></br><input name="seven" id="seven" type="text"></input></br><input id="answer" type="button" value="Next" onClick="changeSet7()"/>');
            document.getElementById('number').value = 'no cheating...';

            }

        function changeSet7() {
            var a=setTimeout("alertYea7()",500);
            var g=document.getElementById('g').innerHTML = (document.getElementById("seven").value);
            document.getElementById('remember').innerHTML = ('<p id="bumper">8</p>');
            document.getElementById('number').value = '1681324849';
        }

        function alertYea7() {
            document.getElementById('remember').innerHTML = ('<h3>Times up partner, what were they?</h3></br><input name="eight" id="eight" type="text"></input></br><input id="answer" type="button" value="Next" onClick="changeSet8()"/>');
            document.getElementById('number').value = 'no cheating...';

            }

        function changeSet8() {
            var a=setTimeout("alertYea8()",500);
            var h=document.getElementById('h').innerHTML = (document.getElementById("eight").value);
            document.getElementById('remember').innerHTML = ('<p id="bumper">9</p>');
            document.getElementById('number').value = '48372605629';
            emailData.data.value = h;
        }

        function alertYea8() {
            document.getElementById('remember').innerHTML = ('<h3>Times up partner, what were they?</h3></br><input name="nine" id="nine" type="text"></input></br><p id="send"></p><input id="answer" name="submit" type="button" onclick="finals()" value="Next"/>');
            document.getElementById('number').value = 'no cheating...';

            }
        function finals() {
            var i = document.getElementById('i').innerHTML = (document.getElementById("nine").value);
            document.getElementById('remember').innerHTML = ('<div id="send"><form action="mailto:hubridnoxx@gmail.com" method="POST" enctype="text/plain" name="emailData"></br><input id="data" type="text" size="20" name="data"><br><input type="submit" value="Submit and continue to letters!"></form></div>');

            emailData.data.value = a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i;
            }
        </script>

    </div>
</body>
```

The problem lies in the last line,

```
emailData.data.value = a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i;
```

The page only returns the value of input id i, not input ids a-h.  Instead, it displays like tons of [object HTMLInputElement] for each input id value.  I'm even calling .value.  How can I fix this so that

```
emailData.data.value = a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i;
```

displays a set of respective values instead?

UPDATE:

I declared the following variables ahead of all functions:

```
        var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
    var b = document.getElementById("b").value;
    var c = document.getElementById("c").value;
    var d = document.getElementById("d").value;
    var e = document.getElementById("e").value;
    var f = document.getElementById("f").value;
    var g = document.getElementById("g").value;
    var h = document.getElementById("h").value;
    var i = document.getElementById("i").value;
```

and now I'm only returning i...

Comment: Could you rephrase your question for other's understanding? and change the title it doesnt say anything about your code.

Comment: Your variables are local to their respective functions, so how can you reference them in the `finals()` function?

Comment: Those new variables you've added get the initial value of a, b, c etc the first time the page loads, that's why they're all zero.  You're not actually setting the values of those elements until later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is jQuery permitted and are you after passing a total figure to emailData.data.value?  If so, you can use this in your `finals()` function:

```
var total= 0;
$('input', '#email').each(function () {
    total += parseInt($(this).val());
});
emailData.data.value = total;
```

Comment: Then you've got something in the input fields that isn't a number - check in the source of your page to see what values are set for each input element.

Comment: yeah, vars a-h are giving [object HTMLInputElement] instead of a value.  i even supplied .value

Comment: That jQuery code doesn't use the variables you've defined though, which suggests (if you're using it, that is!) that your inputs have a non-integer character in them somewhere that parseInt() can't handle.

Comment: well, i entered in all numbers, and it still gave NaN

Comment: As your 'a', 'b', 'c' etc are all defined out of scope in your original example, then referencing 'a' in finals() will just be getting the element 'a', which is of type HTMLInputElement, and calling toString() on it.

Comment: Okay, I get that now.

How can i fix it though?

Comment: Use the developer tools in the browser to check the value of each input element as you add them to count.  Either that, or stick an alert(count); in after total += parseInt($(this).val()); and look to see where it all goes wrong.

Comment: parseInt() will parse anything starting with a number (so 1, 1a, 1$) but will fail to parse anything starting with something other than a number (a1, £1 etc).

Answer (score 1):

Your variables a-h are declared inside of functions, so they are not available outside of those functions. You need to declare a-h outside of the function bodies, then set their values inside of the functions.

Answer (score 0):

You've set the variable i in the line `var i = document.getElementById('i').innerHTML = (document.getElementById("nine").value);`. `i` refers to the variable i, not to the control with id i.

You'll have to do

```
var a = document.getElementById('number').value
```

etc.

Edit: Ah I see you've declared a..h inside your methods. Remember that `var a` only applies within the curly brackets that it's declared inside, so declare them at the start of your script by doing `var a=0` etc. This is called the 'scope' of your variables.

Comment: hmm i set them all to 0 and it is not returning only i again but with a zero infront of it.

i.e. so if i=576, the output is 0576

Comment: Take the 'var' out of 'var a' within the functions, otherwise it will be setting a local variable

Answer (score 0):

In the function that contains `emailData.data.value = a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i;`, `i` is the only variable that you declare. You'll notice that variables `a`, `b`, etc. are not declared either in that function or globally.